# Parsing JSON object in JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a Json object as following.

```
{
"firstName":"John", 
"lastName":"Doe"
"123":"456"
}
```

I want to access they keys and value. After reaching, I will set them into fields. But I don’t why it doesn’t work. I’ve checked its syntax has no problem.

What I’ve tried,

```
$(document).ready(function f() {
    $.ajax('http://soner.dev/test.txt', {
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            $(data).each(function(i,val)
            {
                $.each(val,function(key,val)
                {
                    console.log(key + " : " + val);     
                    alert(key + " : " + val);  
                    $('#{key}').val(val);   
                });
            });
            setTimeout(f, 1000); // refresh the data at each second(data changes at each 1sec)
        }
    });
});
```

By the way, `$('#{key}').val(val);` in which I try to use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: what is `$(data)`?

Comment: "I have a Json array" ...that's your first mistake. What you've got is an object, not an array. An array is something like `[ "abc", "def", hij" ]`

Comment: That's not an array.  It's an object.  And `JSON.parse(string)` parses JSON

Comment: @Taplar but, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_parse_json ??

Comment: That's not a valid array in JSON format (JSON is a text format). That *is* a valid object in JSON format, however. You might want to look over that documentation for Template Literals again; you need to use the tick mark, not the single quote, and use the dollar sign, not the pound symbol.

Comment: @snr what are you trying to say about that link? What's your point?

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to take away from that link.  It doesn't contradict what I said at all

Comment: @HereticMonkey pound symbol to access id element of an html.

Comment: Then you want the pound symbol *and* a dollar sign symbol. The dollar sign is used to denote the following curly brackets are a replaced item.

Comment: @ADyson isn’t there JSON array? var obj = JSON.parse('{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}');

Comment: Arrays use `[]`, not `{}`.  `[1, 2, 3]` is an array

Comment: @snr I already showed you an example of an array in my first comment....did you actually read what I wrote? :-s

Comment: @ADyson and the others,  hummm, forgive me dear guys. **I’ve edited the question. Ascribe to my inexperience in JS**

Comment: I assumed @snr meant that `data` was an array of objects, hence the double `$.each`

Comment: Your data is a plain text. To use template literal, you should put your variable between `${` and `}`

Comment: @pathurs asumptions is how we get stuck on a question trying to solve problems that we make up, rather than solving the OPs actual problem.  which is why we ask questions in comments, not just answer based off our assumptions

Comment: @Taplar of course. I was attempting to help by giving a possible explanation as  the OP is obviously new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an **object** there, not an array. In JSON, objects are wrapped with `{` and `}` and have **named properties** like "firstName" etc. Arrays are wrapped with `[` and `]` and have **numbered indexes** like 0, 1, 2 etc.

Consequently you can make your looping a lot simpler and just iterate over the object keys directly.

N.B. You also need to parse the data from JSON (i.e. a notation format in plain text) into a JavaScript variable before you can begin. Since you're using jQuery's [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you can set the `dataType: "json"` option which causes jQuery to process the response as JSON and parse it for you automatically before it provides the data to your callback.

I also fixed your template literal syntax - you need to use backticks (`) and the dollar sign to make it work.

Here's a runnable demo (using a dummy endpoint since yours doesn't support CORS):

```js
$(document).ready(function f() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/ntsyj",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      console.log(key + " : " + val);
      $(`#${key}`).val(val);
    });
    //setTimeout(f, 1000); // refresh the data at each second(data changes at each 1sec)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="firstName" />
<input id="lastName" />
<input id="123" />
```

Comment: `$.getJSON()` is also an option, for us lazy developers, :)

Comment: Thank you indeed but I don’t understand the meaning of  `(using a dummy endpoint since yours doesn't support CORS)`.

Comment: @snr I can't make an AJAX request to your original URL because it doesn't allow [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (i.e. cross-domain) AJAX requests. So I just substituted it for a URL which does, so that the demo will run. [myjson](http://myjson.com/) is a useful site which lets you add snippets of JSON and expose them via a URL, precisely for testing this kind of code. Anyway that's just an irrelevant detail.  The main point of my answer is the changes to the actual code, not the URL. Did it help you? If so then please consider marking as accepted - thanks :-)

Comment: @ADyson of course every letter is invaluable for me. I just wonder its meaning. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The response is a plain string so yo. firstly, you need to parse it using build-in `JSON.parse()` function and then you can iterate over it.

To use `template literal`, you should put your variable between `${` and `}`.

Please consider the code bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function f() {
    $.ajax('http://soner.dev/test.txt', {
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(parsedData, function( key, val ) {
                console.log(key + " : " + val);     
                alert(key + " : " + val);  
                $(`#${key}`).val(val);
            });
            setTimeout(f, 1000); // refresh the data at each second(data changes at each 1sec)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn’t alert and console.log ? Can you exemplify it on jsfiddle?

Comment: You can't make ajax request in jsfiddle because of `CORS` but I've tested it and it works as you expected. I've got three alert each second containing object keys and values.